# How to use "FullTextQuery" for metadata date field of a component?

Tags: 2011, core-service

Following code is returing me all the component list in 'compList' where **Test_Date** field in metadata is having value.

```
var Querydata = new SearchQueryData
{
FullTextQuery = "Test_Date",
ItemType = New ItemType[] {ItemType.Component}
};

ItendifiableObjectData[] compList = Client.GetSearchResult(queryData);
```

My question is if i need to list only those component whose "Test_Date" metadata field value is equal to a specific date. How to use this FullTextQuery?

Tried `FullTextQuery = "Test_Date=2014-01-29T10:58:05"` But not able to get any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just tried the below query and it now returning all the components with the specific date value:
    `FullTextQuery = " 2014-01-29T10\\:58\\:05* in Test_Date ",`

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the API and at what's possible through the GUI, I'd say you need to specify a schema using a BasedOnSchemaData object and set its Field and FieldValue property

something like:

```
BasedOnSchemaData basedSchemaNote = new BasedOnSchemaData();
basedSchemaNote.Schema = new LinkToSchemaData() { IdRef = "{your schema id}" };
basedSchemaNote.Field = "{schema DateField name}";
basedSchemaNote.FieldValue = "{date value}";
```

Comment: Thanks @Reinder .. actually i have a **Test_Date** date field common in more than four Schemas, that is why i was trying to list all the components  having date field value equal to a specific date without specifying a single Schema.

Comment: I checked from my end the above code is working for all the other metadata fields like dropdown, textbox. The only thing its not working is for date field. Suppose we are passing `FullTextQuery = " Test_dropdowncontrol = testcontent",` it will return list of all the components where the perticular metadata field **Test_dropdowncontrol** is having value as **testcontent**

Comment: what are you passing as a date value?

Comment: `2014-01-28T10:58:05`  this is what i am passing as a value for date field.